# Jquery Ajax is not working with Phonegap

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile

I'm new to Phonegap. I'm trying to use AJAX call in my mobile application, when i call the url, I'm getting error. No result is coming for me from the url which i'm using . when i try the same URL in browser i'm getting the result in json format.

I'm getting the error as Connection closed in the Ajax request headers.

Any suggestion are welcomed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check your config.xml file in res/xml folder
and replace access origin with the following code

```
<access origin="*" />
```

also check the minifest file if you have enabled the following permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: Thanks Vicky i will check this, I have enabled uses-permission , i will check the access in my system. Thanks for the quick reply

Comment: It seems to revert itself whenever I re build it.
EDIT: worked when I edit in <dir>\www\config.xml