# getJSON not working when call from android webview

Tags: java, javascript, android, jquery, getjson

Following is my function from javascript. I tried to call it from browser. It's working. But when I call it from android webview, I don't get any data. I have given internet permission in android manifest. Please help me.

```
function getFileList(){
$("#content").html("<h3>file list:</h3>");
    $.getJSON("http://192.168.1.173:8081/StockTaking/listStock.jsp"+ "?rdm=" + Math.random(),               
                function(data){             
                    $.each(data.filelist,function(i,val){                           
                        $("#content").append("<p>"+data.filelist[i]"</p>");
                });
                });
}
```

Comment: can u access it on device's browser?   ( device's browser : not in app webview)

Comment: yap I tried to access this url from my phone browser and I got the result.

Comment: `http://192.168.1.173:8081/StockTaking/listStock.jsp`    this url right?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16119793/jquery-ajax-is-not-working-with-phonegap/16119921#16119921  check this

Comment: I can't find config.xml Vicky. Where is it?

Comment: You are using phonegap right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After several attempts, I got it by changing android targetSdkVersion from 17 to 15 in manifest.xml.

Answer (score -1):

You need to allow urls with whitelisting

[check this](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/android/9781449361907/4dot-webview-webkit-and-websettings/_domain_whitelisting_html)